# Reverse Quotes in a document using Regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have a document which contains lots of sentences in quotes. Issue is that some of them are properly quoted and some of them have reverse quotes, meaning the opening quotes are at the end of the sentence and closing quotes in the beginning. Like so:
**’’المعلقات السبعہ‘‘** 
Proper sentence should be like this: 
**‘‘المعلقات السبعہ’’** 
I need to write a Regex which will only change the sentences between reverse quotes.
The issue can properly be seen in Word.

For some reason the following Regex is not working properly. Its taking into account the correct ones also. 
`\x{2019}{2}(.+?)\x{2018}{2}`

Comment: Please show the *exact* command you were using. I guess you missed some quotes around the backslashes.

Comment: The exact command is `\x{2019}{2}(.+?)\x{2018}{2}`

Comment: You marked the Answer Correct : What was your Issue ? What regex did you use to resolve that ?

Comment: I saw your comment that the Issue Persists. There may be a Solution but that would require a larger sample of text to test. Is it Possible to include a Paragraph (or a Page) where both types of quotes are messing your regex ? Maybe you could upload it somewhere & Point it here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these Unicode syntax variants

\x{}
`(\x{2019})\x{2019}(.+?)\x{2018}(\x{2018})`
$3$3$2$1$1
https://regex101.com/r/1OwVoT/1

or

\uDDDD
`(\u2019)\u2019(.+?)\u2018(\u2018)`
$3$3$2$1$1
https://regex101.com/r/xZiBxu/1

Answer (score 1):

Your ticks may not be made of one character only.
When I copy and paste your text, I get the following for your four ticks
in the order that they appear in your post:

```
E2 80 99 : U+2019 ’ RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
E2 80 98 twice : U+2018 ‘ LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
E2 80 98 twice : U+2018 ‘ LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
E2 80 99 twice : U+2019 ’ RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

If my tools aren't confusing themselves, this explains why your regex
is failing, and I note in that case that your text-editor is doing
strange things.

Reference :
[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters page with code points U+2000 to U+207F](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).

Comment: Yes the ticks are not made of one character.  Two ticks makes an opening quote, similary same thing ofr closing quote. The document which needs this rectification is approximatly 15 years old.

Comment: With this information you may construct a regex that works.

Comment: I am not convinced ( & may be OP is confused to mark it resolved ) but In OP Post itself it says \x{2018}{2} [ & \x{2019}{2} ] , where we see repetition of 2. I **think** this Answer is not right.

Comment: @Prem I rechecked after your answer, I see that the problem still persists. It is convering the already corrected sentences also thereby make the issue more worse.